# Dynamically setting property inside own class

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, properties

I think I'm very close to have this figured out, but I haven't made progress for some time now and don't really have a choice but to ask around.

I have a `GraphicsSettings` class with a large set of graphics properties. These properties have a placeholder value with the property's name, which I use for a comparison loop.

The comparison loop is a function inside the class, and is between an array of the graphics properties and a `Stringreader` going over lines in an external text file.

When the loop finds a match between the value of a graphics property and a part of what is in a line, I want to set the entire value of the line into the graphics property.

Here's the problem though, I do not know how to call the property setter from within the class without specifically typing out it's name, which I cannot do since its a loop.

I've tried using:

```
this.GetType().GetProperty(key).SetValue(this,line, null);
```

Where "key" is the property name and "line" is the line value. From what I understand, this should work just fine when calling a class object from the outside to set a value, but it seems to be utterly against calling a class from the inside using this method.

All I get is a
 `TargetInvocationException was unhandled` error. Not too surprising, but I dont know how to get around this.

So I guess it comes down to this: How do I access a property through the use of a string, from inside the same class where the property resides?

Comment: I think you need to post some code, including the line that throws the exception, because this should be no issue.

Comment: Also, a `TargetInvocationException` can be quite deceptive. Be sure to check out all nested InnerExceptions, because most likely they will give you a better idea of the true, underlying cause.

Comment: There is no direct reason that line should fail assuming that `key` is in fact the property name (**case sensitive**) and that line doesn't break any type boundaries (e.g. setting `null` to an `int`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the properties are not public, you might need to use binding flags, because the `GetProperty` method does not know, that you are calling it from within the target class. C#'s accessibility rules apply to the static code text and do not apply here.

```
PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic);
prop.SetValue(this, "data", null);
```

Note that finding a property is case sensitive. Therefore you also might need to include the `IgnoreCase` flag.

```
PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
prop.SetValue(this, "data", null);
```

If your properties were static, you would specify the `BindingFlags.Static` flag instead of `BindingFlags.Instance` flag. You can also combine both as well as `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public` for mixed cases.

---

Note also that the types must match. The implicit type conversions of C# do not work here. So always provide the correct type for the value parameter (second parameter) of `SetValue`. E.g.

```
string input = "123";
prop.SetValue(this, Int32.Parse(input), null);

int i = 77;
prop.SetValue(this, (double)i, null);
```

Also convert an `int` to a `double` explicitly, if the property is of type `double`.

---

Chris Kerekes suggests using `prop.MemberType` in conjunction with `Convert.ChangeType` to get a fully dynamic approach that will work if you have properties with different types (at least for the most common types).

```
prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(line, prop.MemberType), null);
```

Comment: Great answer although I'd probably recommend conversion for clr types via `prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(line, prop.MemberType), null);`

Comment: @Chris Kerekes: Yes, your solution allows a very dynamic approach.